# How to find the cumulative Month to Date sum of distinct values in SQL

Tags: ssms

I have the following Table

```
CustomerID FName  LName   Score  Int_Score  Contact_Date
----------+------+------+-------+----------+------------- 
10          John   Doe      20     NULL      2014-01-28
10          John   Doe      30     NULL      2014-01-28 
10          John   Doe      20     NULL      2014-01-28
10          John   Doe      40       10      2014-02-10
10          John   Doe      20     NULL      2014-02-25
10          John   Doe      20     NULL      2014-03-25
10          John   Doe      40       10      2014-03-10
10          John   Doe      50       25      2014-04-28
10          John   Doe      20     NULL      2015-01-25
10          John   Doe      50       25      2015-01-28
```

From this table I want to calculate Resultant score in Cumulative Year to Date form. Here is the calculation for Resultant score- 
Resultant Score = Distinct Score + Distinct Int_Score

For Jan2014
 = 20+30=50 (Only one score of 20 is considered) 
For Feb2014
=  40+10=50 (The score of 20 is added here as it was already accounted for in Jan 2014) 
For Mar2014
= 0 (The score of 20 is added here as it was already accounted for in Jan 2014. Similarly 40,10 was already accounted for in Feb 2015 )
For Apr2014
=50+25=75
For Jan2015 (All scores are reset in new year and the calculation starts for all Score Values)
 =20+50+25 = 95 
Based on the above, I want a result table as

```
CustomerID   Year   Month   Score
-----------+------+-------+-------
10           2014     1      50
10           2014     2      50
10           2014     3       0
10           2014     4      75 
10           2015     1      95
```

Please note that the size of the table is huge with around 1 bn entries and is updated on a daily basis.

Comment: Jan-2014 would be 20+30+20, no? Also, year-to-date means from January  1st till now. Your calculations show rather month-to-date. Which is it?

Comment: @AlexPakka: Month-Date. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AlexPakka Jan 2014 will be 20+30. As each value should be considered only once, we do not consider the second 20

Answer (score 0):

General approach is always to use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT CustomerID, 
       DATEPART(Year,Contact_Date), 
       DATEPART(Month,Contact_Date), 
       SUM(DISTINCT Score)+COALESCE(Int_Score,0)
GROUP BY CustomerId, 
         DATEPART(Year, Contact_Date), 
         DATEPART(Month, Contact_Date)
```

There is nothing really you can do to speed it up. It will run for hours if you have to sum up all the billion rows. I suggest adding WHERE with date ranges and maybe `customerID IN`. And, of course, it's a must that Contact_Date and CustomerID are indexed fields. If it is a single index, then they have to be in the order of GROUP BY: (CustomerId, Contact_Date)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Hope it works as you expected. But performance wise I am not sure.

```
 SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, CONTRACT_YEAR, CONTRACT_MONTH,
        SUM(SCORE+INT_SCORE)
 FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID, YEAR(CONTRACT_DATE) AS CONTRACT_YEAR, MONTH(CONTRACT_DATE)  AS CONTRACT_MONTH, SCORE, ISNULL(INT_SCORE,0) AS INT_SCORE
       FROM TABLE
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE B 
                         WHERE B.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
                           AND B.SCORE = A.SCORE
                           AND B.INT_SCORE = A.INT_SCORE
                           AND B.CONTRACT_DATE < A.CONTRACT_DATE)) AS TABLEA
  GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, CONTRACT_YEAR, CONTRACT_MONTH
```